# Problem when we reboot webrole in Azure

Tags: azure

I have deployed one web application on window Azure portal and after connecting to RDP of that instance I have also installed on service and created on certificate in IIS.
Now when this webrole will reboot , all data (certificate & window service) will lost. 
so to handle this situation which options can be possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is handle these activities as startup tasks which will get executed every time your role starts. Check out this link for more information on startup tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg456327.aspx.

Comment: Yes Gaurav you right..
can you please suggest me how can i install certificate to IIS through console application?? because certificate i already present in application directory which i need to install in IIS of RDP by startup task you have suggested.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/ba319ba7-acb9-4b72-bbc4-4fa84221f21f/. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added startup task with 
Addcert.cmd : 
  certutil -addstore root Startup\MyCert.cer 
still i am not able to see that certificate in certmgr or IIS